# Margin problem not set in tablet view and mobile view

Tags: html, css

[This is mobile view[This is desktop view[This is tablet view][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nRHk.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKuyB.jpg) Hello, I make HTML and CSS  icon box shadow hover effect. The desktop's resolution  is perfect. But tablet view and mobile's  view is not fit with display size. It seems like a resolution issue. Could you please help me to fix issue?
Here i send my code and pics.

HTML

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.container .box .icon {
  width: 120px;
  top: -45px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.icon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:hover {
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.box:hover .icon:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.container .box .content h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .box .content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>enter image description here
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg_info/l/31895/0/icon.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/intex.css">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon i_tools"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Our vision</h3>
        <p>Our firm continuously strives to be the Premier Accounting and Consultancy firm that provides excellent service to our clients and an excellent quality of life for our associates.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon i_bulb"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Our mission</h3>
        <p>Our firm continuously strives to be the Premier Accounting and Consultancy firm that provides excellent service to our clients and an excellent quality of life for our associates.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon i_handshake"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Our value</h3>
        <p>Our firm continuously strives to be the Premier Accounting and Consultancy firm that provides excellent service to our clients and an excellent quality of life for our associates.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use media query it will be easy for you.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
     /*your css code for mobile devices
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
     /*your css code for Tablet devices
}
```

Add this code in your css file and write css for those devices.

Answer (score 0):

like sanjib said use mediaqueries. When you style your html like you're doing now, you styling it in the way it looks good for your screen. luckily most pc's and laptops have almost the same sizes so that's why it look good on desktop.

in addition to Sanjib's answer:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
     /*your css code for mobile devices
}
```

the 767px stands for the pixel things start to appear to be different. this 767px can be changed to a digit of choice.

if you want to fix it you can open inspector mode and click on the mobile tablet logo in the left corner on the downside.

when you do that you can see a certain resolution just click on that and press the down arrow and hold it wil go down with 1px very fast. when things start to shift that wil be your digit that you replace for 767px.

keep in mind you select the width if you want to replace the 767px if you choose height it will be .

`@media only screen and (max-device-heigth: 767px) {
     /*your css code for mobile devices
}`